# Problem with libxml2 and Unicode char in XML Soap with Qotes (") and &amp;quot;

Tags: iphone, unicode, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 for SOAP-Actions in an iPhone App.

The big problem is that i want send an SQL-Statement with

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT test FROM database WHERE test = \"string\""
```

But libxml2 converts the qotes `"` into `&amp;quot;`

Any ideas how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotations within the texual data of XML are supposed to be converted to `&quot;`, per the XML specification.  The receiver is responsible for converting `&quot;` back to quotations when extracting the text from the XML.